# L1 constraint on vectors of a matrix

Tags: matrices, optimization, normed-spaces, non-convex-optimization

I am trying to solve below minimization problem (rank $k$ approximation of a matrix) which is somewhat sparse SVD

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{B,\Lambda}{\text{minimize}}
& & ||A-B\Lambda B^T||_F^2 \\
& \text{subject to}
& & |b_k|_1 \leq \lambda, \; k = 1, \ldots, K.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where $A \in R^{n \times n}$ is a symmteric matrix, $B \in R^{n \times K}$, $\Lambda \in R^{K \times K}$ is a diagonal matrix and  $b_k$ is $k^{th}$ column of $B$ matrix. I am using alternate minimization to solve the above problem and proximal operator for incorporating $L1$ constraint. Whenever I try to decrease the value of $\lambda$, the algorithm always return some $b_k$ 0, where $k$ is close to $K$. Below is an example of $B$ matrix [image]

I want columns of the matrix sparse, I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Two things: 1) this isn't convex _even in alternate minimization_; in particular it is not convex in $B$. 2) What does $b_k\leq\lambda$ mean? $b_k$ is a vector, $\lambda$ a scalar?

Comment: @MichaelGrant Edited the question

Comment: You're saying minimization over $x$, but there is no $x$ in the model. I guess you mean $B$.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg You are right, edited the question.

Comment: Why don't you just solve directly $\min ||A-BLB^T||_F + \rho ||b_k||_i$ where $\rho>0$ is a tuning parameter and $i=1$. This promotes sparsity. You can further promote sparsity by using the 0-norm, i.e., set $i=0.$ (I know that this is not really a norm...)

Comment: this looks like this algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-SVD

Comment: @CharlesF I tried solving that problem and it gave me the result which is showed in the question. As we know some components ($b_k$) would have more weight and some will have less weight, so the algorithm is making $b_k$ 0 which has less weight. I want to have all $b_k$ somewhat equally sparse.

Comment: @DushyantSahoo Can you formally define what you mean by "equally sparse?"